# Nginx rewrite rule to make php see https scheme

Tags: nginx, https, php-fpm, php5

I want my pho application to only see the https scheme even if the secure connection is already terminated.

I have the following setup:
Browser --https--> nginx --http--> nginx --> php-fpm socket

Now I need the php application to only note about the original https scheme request.

Is that even possible?

The only alternative I see is to make the nginx to nginx traffic also over https. But I want to avoid the overhead for local traffic.

Comment: Another way would be to hope that the application handles x-forwarded-proto headers. I will check that as well.

Comment: The PHP application will probably use either `$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` to determine the scheme. These parameters can be set and/or overridden in your Nginx configuration file.

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO ist just the head field. How to override the REQUEST_SCHEME?

Comment: Maybe this is what I need? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/fastcgiexample/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to override the properties using `fastcgi_param REQUEST_SCHEME 'https';` after `include fastcgi.conf;`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param   REQUEST_SCHEME  'https';
    fastcgi_param   HTTPS           'on';
}
```